# Angular Protractor not detecting rendered component tag

Tags: angular, jasmine, protractor, e2e-testing, angular-e2e

I want to check if my `app.component.htm` has the tag `chart` html tag necessary to render my `chartComponent`.

```
// app.e2e-spec.ts

import { AppPage } from './app.po';
import { by, element } from 'protractor';

describe('App', () => {
  let page: AppPage;

  beforeEach(() => {
    page = new AppPage();
  });

  it('should have a chart element', () => {
    page.navigateTo();
    const elem =  element(by.css('chart'));
    expect(elem.isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Then the component:

```
// app.component.html
<chart></chart>
```

Always fails with `- Failed: script timeout: result was not received in 11 seconds`

What is wrong with it? The `chart` element rendered as expected in the browser.

Comment: I just tried replicating what you posted and couldn't. For starters the closing `chart` tag is missing the `/` (not sure if intentional). Secondly, it doesn't actually show up in my page, I just have an empty `app-root`. Also my IDE says: " 'chart' is not a known element:
1. If 'chart' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component."
Can you please provide more information on how to replicate?

Comment: `<chart>` is a custom component - for brevity I did not include the code, but assume its a regular angular component generated with Angular CLI. The closing tag was a typo, in my app it is closed properly. Try to embed any custom component and then reference the html with protractor.